# How to correctly UploadAsync to Azure page blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

That's how I upload to azure page blob storage

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(range, offsetToTransfer, sizeToTransfer, false, false);
pageBlob.WritePages(memoryStream, vhdOffset + offsetToTransfer, null);
Console.WriteLine("Range ~" + Megabytes(offsetToTransfer + vhdOffset) + " + " + PrintSize(sizeToTransfer));`
```

Azure recommend me to use this [library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) to upload etc.

How can I set second parameter (it's offset) `vhdOffset + offsetToTransfer` to `UploadAsync`? I mean how can I specify a `position` where I want to write?

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(range, offsetToTransfer, sizeToTransfer, false, false);
TransferManager.UploadAsync(memoryStream, pageBlob);
```

Comment: DataMovement Library is used for uploading the whole stream/file to page blob, it doesn't support writing to a specified offset.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to write a page with an offset, you may use the CloudPageBlob.WritePagesAsync API wich is documented here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudpageblob.writepagesasync(v=azure.10).aspx

There a complete sample based on CloudPageBlob.WritePages API here.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/04/10/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs/

The following code :

```
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(range, 
                       offsetToTransfer, sizeToTransfer, false, false);
    pageBlob.WritePages(memoryStream, vhdOffset + offsetToTransfer);
```

allows you to write a sequential set of pages up to 4MBs, and the offset being written to must start on a 512 byte boundary (startingOffset % 512 == 0), and end on a 512 boundary – 1.

Hope this helps

Best regards

Stéphane